# Como customizar a biblioteca Doctrine para trabalhar com o tipo Timestamp

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer, doctrine, timestamp

Eu estou utilizando o Composer com o Doctrine em minha aplicação, e está ficando maravilhoso. Porém estou precisando customizar algumas funcionalidades do Doctrine, alterando as classes `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform` e `Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform`.

Para isto eu criei as classes `MY_AbstractPlatform` e `MY_MySqlPlatform` e extendi as respectivas superclasses. Então, eu as adicionei em meu autoload, mas nada aconteceu.

Quando eu escrevo o código diretamente nas classes do Doctrine a customização é realizada, porém quando eu implemento os respectivos métodos nas subclasses nada acontece.

Estou precisando customizar a biblioteca do Doctrine, mas como fazer isso?

Comment: Antes de mais nada, seria possível falar o motivo da customização, para que a comunidade possa discutir se a mesma seria realmente necessária? :)

Comment: Olá Rodrigo Rigotti, atualizei a pergunta, inserindo a solução que encontrei hoje de manhã. A customização que eu desejava era para trabalhar com campos timestamp, pois já tenho uma base de dados em produção que não pode ser modificada, e a mesma faz uso deste tipo constantemente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer a customização de forma modularizada. Ou seja, consegui criar as subclasses do Doctrine na minha aplicação e utilizá-las a partir da configuração da conexão, definindo a propriedade `driverClass` do array de conexão, instanciando a classe do meu driver `MY_Driver`.

Veja como configurei a conexão Doctrine, atenção para a propriedade 'driverClass':

```
$connection_options = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => $db['default']['username'],
            'password' => $db['default']['password'],
            'host' => $db['default']['hostname'],
            'dbname' => $db['default']['database'],
            'charset' => $db['default']['char_set'],
            'driverOptions' => array(
                'charset' => $db['default']['char_set'],
            ),
            'driverClass' => new MY_Driver()
        );
```

Como o meu objetivo era permitir que o Doctrine trabalhasse com campos **timetamp**, criei uma classe para representar o Driver da minha aplicação, herdando a classe Driver nativa do Doctrine. Minha subclasse declara uma outra subclasse `MY_MySqlPlatform` contendo as  personalizações para a plataforma MySql para aplicar o **timestamp**.

```
class MY_Driver extends Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\Driver {

    /**
     * Define a classe personalizada para o driver da plataforma MySql
     * 
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDatabasePlatform() {

        return new MY_MySqlPlatform();
    }

}
```

A classe `MY_MySqlPlatform` herda a classe`MySqlPlatform` nativa do Doctrine, porém aplicando métodos próprios para uso do tipo timestamp.

```
class MY_MySqlPlatform extends Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getDateTimeTypeDeclarationSQL(array $fieldDeclaration) {
        if (isset($fieldDeclaration['version']) && $fieldDeclaration['version'] == true) {
            return 'TIMESTAMP';
        }

        return 'TIMESTAMP';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL(array $fieldDeclaration) {
        return 'TIMESTAMP';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function initializeDoctrineTypeMappings() {
        $this->doctrineTypeMapping = array(
            'tinyint' => 'boolean',
            'smallint' => 'smallint',
            'mediumint' => 'integer',
            'int' => 'integer',
            'integer' => 'integer',
            'bigint' => 'bigint',
            'tinytext' => 'text',
            'mediumtext' => 'text',
            'longtext' => 'text',
            'text' => 'text',
            'varchar' => 'string',
            'string' => 'string',
            'char' => 'string',
            'date' => 'date',
            'datetime' => 'datetime',
            'timestamp' => 'timestamp',
            'time' => 'time',
            'float' => 'float',
            'double' => 'float',
            'real' => 'float',
            'decimal' => 'decimal',
            'numeric' => 'decimal',
            'year' => 'date',
            'longblob' => 'blob',
            'blob' => 'blob',
            'mediumblob' => 'blob',
            'tinyblob' => 'blob',
            'binary' => 'blob',
            'varbinary' => 'blob',
            'set' => 'simple_array',
        );
    }

}
```

E por fim criei a classe `TimestampType` em meu projeto, herdando a classe `Type` nativa do Doctrine, para representar um atributo do tipo Tymestamp durante o mapeamento.

```
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class TimestampType extends Type {

    const TIMESTAMP = 'timestamp';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName() {
        return self::TIMESTAMP;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform) {

        return $platform->getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        return ($value !== null) ? $value->format($platform->getTimestampTypeDeclarationSQL()) : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform) {
        if ($value === null || $value instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $value;
        }

        $val = \DateTime::createFromFormat($platform->getDateTimeFormatString(), $value);
        if (!$val) {
            throw ConversionException::conversionFailedFormat($value, $this->getName(), $platform->getDateTimeFormatString());
        }

        return $val;
    }

}
```